# LinkedIn API OAUTH returning "grant_type" error

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am pretty new to coding, but trying to write a simple script using LinkedIn's API that will pull an organizations follower count into google app script. Before I can even query the API, I have to authenticate using oath explained in the LinkedIn API [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow?context=linkedin/context#step-3-make-api-requests).

This function returns with an error response

```js
function callLinkedAPI () {

  var headers = {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": "78ciob33iuqepo",
    "client_secret": "deCgAOhZaCrvweLs"
     }

  var url = `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken/`

  var requestOptions = {
    'method': "POST",
    "headers": headers,
    'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
    };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  
  console.log(json)

  }
```

When I try sending the headers through I get this error as a response

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"A required parameter \"grant_type\" is missing"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grant_type`, `client_id`, `client_secret` do not go in the header of the request. Instead, try to put them in the body of the POST request with the content type `x-www-form-urlencoded` as you already had in the headers of the code you posted.

For example:

```
fetch('https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
    },
    body: new URLSearchParams({
      grant_type: 'client_credentials',
      client_id: '78ciob33iuqepo',
      client_secret: 'deCgAOhZaCrvweLs'
    })
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseData => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(responseData))
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Apps Script  you should send the payload like so:

### Example:

```js
function callLinkedAPI() {

  var payload = {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": "78ciob33iuqepo",
    "client_secret": "deCgAOhZaCrvweLs"
  }
  
  var url = `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken/`

  var requestOptions = {
    'method': "POST",
    'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    "payload":payload
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);

  console.log(json)

}
```